# Understanding EventTrigger in XAML without arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I am understanding `EventTriggers` and I came across a code like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger>
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My question is:

When will this `EventTrigger` actually fire as there are no arguments in the EventTrigger and how will the EventTrigger know on which event should it run the command `OnLoadedCommand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `EventName` property is not specified, the `DefaultEventAttribute` of the Control is used to determine the default event.

For example, the default event for the Button control is the `Click` event.

[`MSDN: DefaultEventAttribute Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cdx1c3yt)